# Not all data is visible via Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Problem summary**

I have encountered strange in behaviour when working with Oracle database via Oracle.ManagedDataAccess: data access components of the app see only that table data that was added from this app.

**Steps to reproduce**

Oracle table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
    "TIMESTAMP" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL
)
```

Test app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before run, count = {0}", GetCount());
        InsertNew();
        Console.WriteLine("After app insert, count = {0}", GetCount());

        Console.WriteLine("Insert row via SQL developer and press enter");
        Console.Read();

        Console.WriteLine("After SQL developer insert, count = {0}", GetCount());

       Console.Read();
    }

    private static void InsertNew()
    {
        using (var connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            var command = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(TIMESTAMP) VALUES(:Timestamp)", connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Timestamp", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = DateTime.Now;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }



    private static int GetCount()
    {
        using (var connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            var command = new OracleCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TEST_TABLE", connection);
            return (int)(decimal)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    private static OracleConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

When the app prompts to insert row via SQL developer I run

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(TIMESTAMP) VALUES(SYSDATE);
```

Connection string looks like:

```
Data Source=DATA_SOURCE_NAME;User Id=USER_ID;Password=PASS;
```

Oracle version: 10g (10.2.0.5.0)
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version: 4.121.2.0

**Results**

On first run I get results:

```
Before run, count = 0
After app insert, count = 1
Insert row via SQL developer and press enter

After SQL developer insert, count = 1
```

On second run I get results:

```
Before run, count = 1
After app insert, count = 2
Insert row via SQL developer and press enter

After SQL developer insert, count = 2
```

So the app sees the data that it has added including data added on previous runs, but doesn't see data added via SQL developer

When queries are run via SQL developer all data is returned

**Question**

So the question is what can cause such behavior? And how to ensure that application can get all the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer - Steps to reproduce has missing step "Press [Commit] in SQL plus" after executing insert.